# Python's request not scraping right content from Google news

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, google-news

I'm trying to scrape all news headlines from Google News (note: not via news.google.com) with the following conditions:

i. keyword(s),
ii. specific date range,
iii. sorted by date, and
iv. able to loop through the pages

This is the link of a regular google search with specified keywords:
https://www.google.com/search?q=migrant%2Bcaravans&rlz=1C1GCEA_enUS827US827&sxsrf=ACYBGNT3ExxxPO5PSo9Cgp91M37sVBHLMA:1576086735805&source=lnms&tbm=nws&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwji9pbQlK7mAhWIxFkKHWDQCCcQ_AUoAXoECBAQAw&biw=1680&bih=939

And this is the link of my google with the same keywords with sorted by date and date range:
https://www.google.com/search?q=migrant%2Bcaravans&rlz=1C1GCEA_enUS827US827&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1/1/2017,cd_max:12/31/2017,sbd:1&tbm=nws&sxsrf=ACYBGNRZjtVzEEfuEKcHjuOYUmubi5pT3g:1576086970386&source=lnt&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjc1oTAla7mAhWExVkKHQlVB_YQpwUIIA&biw=1680&bih=939&dpr=1

This is a sample of my code that is able to scrape the headlines from a regular search without any of the conditions imposed:

```
def scrape_news_summaries(topic, pagenum=1):
#time.sleep(randint(0, 2))
url = "http://www.google.com/search?q="+topic+"&tbm=nws&dpr=" + str(pagenum)
r = requests.get(url)
if r.status_code != 200:
    print('status code for ' + url + ' was ' + str(r.status_code))
    sys.exit(-1)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

return soup

scrape_news_summaries("migrant+caravans")
```

This is the code with the altered the URL to include a date range and have the search sorted by date:

```
def scrape_news_date_range(query, min_date, max_date, pagenum=1):
url = "https://www.google.com/search?q="+query+"&rlz=1C1GCEA_enUS827US827&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:"+min_date+",cd_max:"+max_date+",sbd:1&tbm=nws/*,ned=es_sv*/&dpr="+str(pagenum)
r = requests.get(url)
if r.status_code != 200:
    print('status code for' + url + 'was' + str(r.status_code))
    sys.exit(-1)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
#return soup
print(soup)
scrape_news_date_range("migrant+caravans", "1/1/2017", "12/1/2017")
```

And it doesn't seem to return the same content as I would like to get from the second link which I shared above instead it returns the content of a regular search.

I greatly appreciate any help with this! Thank you so much!

Comment: Try to set `User-Agent' header to something, e.g `headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:71.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/71.0'}` when doing request.

Comment: Have you looked to see how Google handles those date parameters that you're sending? I wouldn't be surprised if there's some JavaScript that's handling the date filtering after the initial request is made. [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) might be you're friend here instead of requests, as you might be stuck waiting for the JavaScript execution before you'll have access to the data that you're looking for.